# How to write a TypeScript overload that specifies either no argument or all?

Tags: typescript, overloading

I want type a function in such a way that it can be called with either no arguments or all arguments (two in my case).

I tried this:

```
function foo(a: string, b: number): string
function foo(a?: string, b?: number): string
function foo(a?: string, b?: number): string {
    return a + (b ? b.toString() : '')
}
```

…but I can still provide just one argument and receive no errors:

```
foo();            // ok
foo('hello', 42); // ok
foo('oops');      // should error, but doesn't
```

Here's a [TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBDAXIgzlAJxjAHMAaRAIxzBAFtKBTAgSh3yNIChRJYFkqTAH52hYuSqjEtBszZ5x3XtHhIU6DNI4SKlabKasxnEogDeXRNcQFGUEASQZEAakRpKiYVQB0UOABlJRI0FkQcAHJIli4AXy4eIRYAbkQAenTEOABrJPRIgAtGABsSuEiKABYAJlSMrNz8tEjUAAdcGLTMvEK4EBKAE0RmAjgCIA).

Is this possible?

Comment: How does it make sense to have `function foo(a?: string, b?: number)` and expect that `foo("oops")` doesn't work? You very explicitly say that *both* parameters are optional, thus zero, one, or two parameters are all valid.

Comment: Also, the function doesn't actually handle the no argument version anyway. With nothing passed for `a` the value of the parameter would be `undefined`. I don't think the body works well with an `undefined`.

Comment: This function is for example purposes and doesn't make much sense, because the function body is irrelevant to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function foo(a: string, b: number): string
function foo(): string // YOU NEED NO ARGS YOU WRITE NO ARGS
function foo(a?: string, b?: number): string {
    return a + (b ? b.toString() : '')
}
```

Comment: Should've known, duh… I think I tried a variant with no args at some point, but obviously not this one. Well deserved caps lock, haha.

Comment: I love `// YOU NEED NO ARGS YOU WRITE NO ARGS` by the way